# Weird NullReferenceException from _Host.cshtml

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am using VS2022.

I am getting this error and I didn't think it was possible.  :)

[image]

Anyone knows what could cause this?  I tried to comment out the @RenderBody in my _Layout.cshtml, but the error persists...very weird.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

**MainLayout.razor**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>TestCoreRazor</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
  </div>

  <main>
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
    </div>

    <article class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </article>
  </main>
</div>
```

**Index.razor**

@page "/"

```
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, Developer!</h1>

<p>If you are reading this, you must be building a custom component.</p>
```

Comment: Can you add your `MainLayout` page and your `index` page?

Comment: @user13256346...added as requested....thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70688076/blazor-server-app-component-suddenly-throwing-null-reference-exception) that has the same symptom and the culprit is the exactly same:

***check the page directive in ALL your page Razor component***...you might have a duplicate

***If you have recently added a component, check all the values that assigned to the properties of the components have been defined correctly.***